Which is the smallest integer $c>0$ making $a\cdot (b+c)$ a pairing function for positive integer $a,b$ with $a \le a_{max}$ and $b \le b_{max}$?
The goal is to generate $a_{max} \cdot b_{max}$ different numbers with
$$a\cdot (b+c)$$
using an integer offset $c>0$ as small as possible.
We know $a \in [1,a_{max}]$, and $b \in[1,b_{max}]$
I'm looking for a formula computing the smallest suitable $c_{min}$, even for larger numbers ($\approx10^{50}$).
No proof required.

An upper bound for $c$ is $c_{max} = a \cdot b$ 
If there is no formula for the absolute minimum. How much smaller can we make this upper bound?

Here are some example values I computed by trying out every possible value



$a$
$b$
$c_{min}$

$a$
$b$
$c_{min}$




2
2
1

2
4
3


3
3
2

3
9
14


4
4
6

4
9
18


5
5
9

10
5
18


8
8
30

10
8
36


10
10
49

5
10
24


20
20
256

5
20
64


32
32
702

16
32
351


47
47
1640

47
113
3960


64
64
3192

47
64
2214


100
100
8190

20
100
1638


113
113
10506

113
47
3536




Bonus question:
Minimal $c>0$ for
$$a\cdot (c-b)$$

It looks to me like $c(a,b) = (a-1)(b-a+1)$ for $b \ge (a-1)(a-2)+1$ (but for $b \ge 2$ in the case $a=2$).  I don't have a proof, nor do I have a formula for when $b \le (a-1)(a-2)$.
EDIT: Well, here's one small piece of the puzzle.
With $b = (a-1)(a-2)$, $c = (a-1)(b-a+1) = (a-1)^2(a-3)$ does not work because
$$  (a-2)((a-1)(a-2) + c) = (a-1)(1+c) $$
So that's why I needed $b \ge (a-1)(a-2)+1$.

Thanks for a possible answer. Haven't found any not working combination yet. I'm mainly interested in a formula for $a,b>3$ and $b \ge a^2$. So not a big deal if is not working for other combinations. Will do some more testing and wait a little longer before marking it as an answer. Might you also have an idea about the similar case $a \cdot (c-b)$?

I think I found some for the alternative pairing function $a \cdot (c-b)$. Very similar to yours: $c_{min} = a \cdot (b-a+2)$, same restrictions for $b$

If we allow $b \in [0,b_{max}]$ it will change to $(a-1)\cdot (b-a+2)+1$ for $a\cdot (c+b)$  and to $a\cdot (b-a+3)-1$ for $a\cdot (c-b)$
